# node-xmpp-bosh error on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, command-line

I am newbie in Linux word. I want to implement a bosh server.

Because it is hard on Windows platform I decided to deploy it on a Ubuntu virtual machine via vmware. I made installation without problems. I followed the processes on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/node-xmpp-bosh/wiki/DebianHowTo).

Now I want to test my bosh server with the command `sudo bosh` or `sudo /etc/init.d/bosh start`, after typing those I get on the terminal

> Starting bosh server

after, nothing. I looked on the `bosh.err` file and I see

> exec: 2: /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js: Permission denied

I don̍ t know why this error with sudo.

When I try `ls -l /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js` it show

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4889 2012-04-01 18:50 /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js

How can I make bosh start?

Answer (score 0):

The OP also asked his [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9969104). There he writes about more problems. However as the error message suggests the file `/usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js` should be made executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/lib/bosh/run-server.js
```